# Error: Class '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docs'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i am trying to get list of a particular uid document from firebase here is the code

```
StreamBuilder(
                        stream: firestore
                            .collection('interest')
                            .doc('${auth.currentUser.uid}')
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                          }
                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Container();
                              });
                        }),
```

Error:

```
Class '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docs'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: docs
```

my collection

[image: the collection image]

i am try to get the list from this document uid
Thanks

Comment: Try `itemCount: snapshot.data['Interest'].length,`

Comment: thanks Error Gone...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I tried using explicit (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) and it worked for me, also I create the listview without the builder:

```
ListView(
children: myList.map((object) {
   return myWidget(object: object);
}).toList(),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).